# Knockout computed observable in hottowel SPA default viewmodel

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, hottowel

I'm trying to create a simple knockout computed observable following the viewmodal pattern in the Hottowel SPA template.  What is the **best** way to do this?

I originally had something like this:

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Home View',
        testField: ko.observable("This is a test"),
        testComputedField: ko.computed(getComputed, this)
    };

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function getComputed() {
        return "Computed: " + this.testField();
    }

    function activate() {
        logger.log('Home View Activated', null, 'home', true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

but this results in an error, though I'm not 100% sure why

```
TypeError: this.testField is not a function
```

So with a bit of trial and error I got to this:

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Home View',
        testField: ko.observable("This is a test")
    };

    vm.testComputedField = ko.computed(getComputed, vm);

    return vm;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function getComputed() {
        return "Computed: " + this.testField();
    }

    function activate() {
        logger.log('Home View Activated', null, 'home', true);
        return true;
    }
    //#endregion
});
```

But I'm not sure this is a very pretty way of doing this; I'm obviously not grokking the module pattern used for viewmodels in HotTowel very well.  So my questions are:

Why doesn't my original method work?
Are there any better or alternate ways to define\structure the viewmodel than my second method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutex, this is the general pattern I am using, it is working well for me.

I use function expressions and local scoped variables for the KO bindings, and function declarations for the Durandal specific methods (activated, viewAttached, etc.).  The vm object needs to be after the function expressions.  Eliminates the need to use 'this' everywhere.

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {

    var testField = ko.observable("This is a test");

    var getComputed = ko.computed(function () {
        return "Computed: " + testField();
    });

    function activate() {
        logger.log('Home View Activated', null, 'home', true);
        return true;
    }

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Home View',
        testField: testField,
        testComputedField: getComputed
    };

    return vm;
});
```

NOTE: This is for the HotTowel SPA template

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your original method:

```
var vm = {
   activate: activate,
   title: 'Home View',
   testField: ko.observable("This is a test"),
   testComputedField: ko.computed(getComputed, this)
};
```

When you pass `this` to the computed.. `this` does not point to your `vm`.  Instead pass in the `vm` itself:

```
var vm = {
   activate: activate,
   title: 'Home View',
   testField: ko.observable("This is a test"),
   testComputedField: ko.computed(getComputed, vm)
};
```

---

EDIT ****
I don't know why the above didn't work.  According to the knockout documentation the second argument should set the `this` context to the method in the first argument.  How about trying this:

```
function getComputed() {
   return "Computed: " + vm.testField();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that has pretty much the same effect as passing "this"  In fact, if I put a breakpoint on the first line of the getComputed function in both cases "this" for the function ends up being the window object.

Comment: this gets into some the complications that arise when defining the view model as an object literal.  A key to making the object literal work is to define your properties and functions separately, then just build your object at the end, similar to how mikekidder's answer demonstrates.  An alternative is to define the view model as a function, exposing properties and function normally, and return a new instance of the function from the module.